# Prevent Orbeon to encode dropdown values by position

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, encoding, orbeon

I want to prevent Orbeon from encoding dropdown values (i.e. values of select options) by position, since I need to use exact values on the client-side via JavaScript.

E.g: My options have values (150, 250, 350), but they are rendered/encoded by position as (1,2,3) on the front-end. I have tried with setting the property in **properties-local.xml**:

```
<property
    as="xs:boolean"
    name="oxf.xforms.encrypt-item-values"
    value="false"/>
```

However, for some reason this doesn't work. Not sure if I am missing something. Does anybody have an idea what could be the reason for this and is it possible that I need to set this property somewhere else?

If matters, I'm using Orbeon forms with hybris Commerce suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form Runner overrides the [`oxf.xforms.encrypt-item-values`](http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/xforms.html#xforms-items-encoding) property, which explains why it has not effect in your case.

If you have only a few controls which require this, you should be able to set the attribute `xxf:encrypt-item-values="false"` directly on the `xf:select1` control in the form source.

This said, I notice that if using a dropdown with `fr:dropdown-select1`, the attribute is not forwarded properly. So I entered an [issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2539) for this.